# Email not going from app installed on AWS

Tags: spring-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have my spring web application hosted on AWS. After user signup it should send email to given email. But i can see that its not sending any email.

I am using a gmail account as sender of email.I don't see any exception or error also in my log.

Comment: How are you sending email? Via sendmail? SMTP? or some other service?

Comment: i sending it through my programm in java

Comment: You might be get blocked as potential spammer. AWS are running automatic checks to detect harmful activity. Either use an email service like sendmail or SES, or contact AWS support to verify that you are not blocked.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the ports, iptables(firewall),
Try sending a test email from the prompt/Bash.

for testing [Linux](http://www.simplehelp.net/2008/12/01/how-to-send-email-from-the-linux-command-line/)
 for testing [Windows](http://www.wikihow.com/Send-Email-Using-Telnet)

If success, with the test, then work on the application.